Drawing squares with defined pixel sizes
Background
I want to create a sheet for multiple-choice answers with the following features:

Generate a marker: Place a QR Code at a specific position on the sheet for alignment and calibration purposes.

Draw answer boxes: Add squares at precise, predefined positions to serve as answer areas.

Standardized sheets: Provide identical answer sheets to students for all exams.

Scan completed sheets: After the exam, scan the sheets at a given dpi to capture responses.

Adjust for alignment: Use the QR Code to detect and correct for any rotation or scaling during scanning (there may be some scaling differences when printing the sheets and sheets may be slightly rotated when scanned).

Retrieve positions: Use the predefined positions of the answer squares to locate the marked responses.

Analyze responses: Measure the intensity within each square to determine if an answer was selected.


LaTeX
I use this code to generate answer boxes. Boxes should have constant gaps in x and y.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{}(5, 1.5)  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define the internal square size (excluding the border) and separation in em units
    \def\squareSize{1.344em}  % Internal size of square (excluding border) 28px
     \def\spacing{1.536em}      % Spacing between squares (for consistency)
     \def\borderThickness{0.096em} % Border thickness in em units (2 pixel border)
    
    % Loop over rows (0 to 19 for 20 rows) and columns (0 to 4 for 5 columns)
    \foreach \row in {0, 1, 2, ..., 19} {
        \foreach \col in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} {
            % Calculate the x and y coordinates for each square
            \pgfmathsetmacro\xPos{\col * (\squareSize + \spacing)} % X position for each square
            \pgfmathsetmacro\yPos{\row * (\squareSize + \spacing)} % Y position for each square

            % If it's the first column in the row, place the label Q1, Q2, etc.
            \ifnum\col=0
                \node[anchor=east, gray!60, font=\sffamily] at (\xPos - \spacing / 2, \yPos + \squareSize / 2) {Q\the\numexpr20-\row\relax}; % Reverse label order
            \fi

            % Draw rectangle with a gray border and thicker lines, adjusting for the border
            \draw[fill=white, draw=gray!60, line width=\borderThickness] 
                (\xPos - \borderThickness/2, \yPos - \borderThickness/2) 
                rectangle (\xPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness/2, \yPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness/2); % Adjusted for border
        }
    }

    % Add labels A, B, C, D, E above the first row of squares
    \foreach \col in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xPos{\col * (\squareSize + \spacing)} % X position for each square
        \node[anchor=south, font=\sffamily, color=gray!60] at (\xPos + \squareSize / 2, 42*\squareSize + \spacing) { 
            \ifcase \col A \or B \or C \or D \or E \fi
        }; % Labels A, B, C, D, E
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}

Document
This code generates multiple squares, as shown below.

Expected size of the squares (in pixels at 150 dpi)
I convert this pdf as a .jpeg image at 150 dpi and overlay squares (green) that have a constant spacing in x and y. There (at 150 dpi), each square (excluding border) should be (assuming 10pt):

1.344*(10/72)*150 or 28 pixels

The border size should be :

0.096*(10/72)*150 or 2 pixels

And the spacing in x and y should be :

1.536*(10/72)*150 or 32 pixels

Issue
As seen on the image, there is a small shift and I suspect my calculations above are not correct or that I am missing something.

Edit
Here is a minimal python code to draw the squares (using the LaTeX modifications below).
import cv2

# Number of rows and columns of squares
rows = 20
cols = 5

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('Original.jpg')

# Define
vertical_spacing = 60
horizontal_spacing =30 
square_size = 30
Offset = (494, 220)

# Draw Squares
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        top_left_x = Offset[0] + col * (square_size + horizontal_spacing) 
        top_left_y = Offset[1] + row * vertical_spacing 
        bottom_right = (top_left_x + square_size, top_left_y + square_size)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (top_left_x, top_left_y), bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 1)

# Show the image
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite('/image_corrected.jpg', image)


What I do :

I compile the LaTeX
I export the .pdf to a .jpg at 150 dpi
I run the .py

Using the proposed modifications
\draw[fill=white, draw=gray!60, line width=\borderThickness] 
(\xPos - \borderThickness/2, \yPos - \borderThickness/2) rectangle 
(\xPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness, \yPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness);

I get this:

And so there is still a shift.
Final
Thank you all for your inputs.
I finally decided not to do it with LaTeX after having spent hours (trying to compute the positions externally). Using Corel Draw took me a few minutes to achieve this, which serves my purpose.


welcome! the inaccuracy is almost certainly not in your calculations but in the TeX implementation. dimension calculations in TeX are never accurate and errors accumulate. if you need higher accuracy, you need a different implementation e.g. the pgf floating point, maybe, or the floating point functions now in the kernel. if you can keep things as integers for longer, that can also work.

Welcome to TeX.SE, nice code!

Thanks. I will double check that my python code that overlays the green rectangles is correct but I guess it is.

but don't you want \draw[fill=white, draw=gray!60, line width=\borderThickness]                  (\xPos - \borderThickness/2, \yPos - \borderThickness/2)                  rectangle (\xPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness, \yPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness); ?

Note that the default origin for PDF is not (0pt,0pt), unless you load geometry or set \pdfpageheight=\paperheight and \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth.  Besides, if you are already using TikZ, you don't need textblock.

What is your goal? This makes me think about https://www.auto-multiple-choice.net/index.fr and https://github.com/sdaps/sdaps .

Indeed. I have edited the post accordingly (Background). I could not install amc on MacOS.

I think you want
\draw[fill=white, draw=gray!60, line width=\borderThickness] 
(\xPos - \borderThickness/2, \yPos - \borderThickness/2) rectangle 
(\xPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness, \yPos + \squareSize + \borderThickness);

because half the line width is not counted as tikz measures these things. That is, a rectangle drawn with line width of 1pt and dimensions 10pt by 10pt will have internal dimensions of 9pt by 9pt i.e. 10pt - 2(1pt/2).

Thanks !! I will check and report in the next 3 hours. Best

@Laut567 I ran the example and it looked as if it might explain the displacement, but I don't have the green square overlay, so hard to tell. ;)

@Laut567 very nice question, by the way :-).

Just have edited and posted a minimal example in python. I guess the problem is not python or the way the .jpeg is generated.

@Laut567 indeed. as I mentioned originally, dimension calculations are not accurate in TeX. that's just how TeX works. in normal typesetting, it is 'good enough'. when inaccuracies accumulate, especially in things like pgf loops, however, the discrepancies can be highly visible. usually, you can avoid this by restructuring. if not, take the calculations out of TeX. use one of the floating point implementations. for example. (or do them in python, if you prefer.) you can't make TeX more accurate than it is.
